# XEN VM networking, public IP binding

Tags: networking, nat, xen, hypervisor

I need some information about routing public IP addresses assigned to the hypervisor into a VM.

I have installed XEN hypervisor on Centos 6.5, I have one NIC with IP 80.86.84.34 & Mask:255.255.255.0 I have an additional IP 85.25.14.195 & Mask: 255.255.255.255

Dom0 has eth0 & virbr0 with a virtual dhcp, the VM has address 192.168.122.4 & Mask:255.255.255.0 the VM has working outbound internet connection.

How do I correctly set dom0 to route connections for 85.25.14.195 into the VM?

Many thanks for your help and apologies if this is a basic question that has been answered before, please point me in the right direction.

**First EDIT**

I have managed to route the public IP by adding the below route in Dom0, DomU now correctly responds to packets received by Dom0 for the public IP forwarded over virbr0.

```
route add -net 85.25.14.195 gw 192.168.122.1 netmask 255.255.255.255
```

My follow up question is what rule is required in IP tables to allow traffic? As currently it is blocked when the firewall is running.

**Second EDIT**

OK, so I figured out the iptables, I had to remove the REJECT line on virbr0, I also had to add the following rule to make the outbound IP from Dom0 appear correctly:

```
-A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.122.2 -p tcp -j SNAT --to 85.25.14.195
```

Comment: I simply use the xenbr0 attached on VM network. Done by edit `vmname.cfg` and change line `vif` value from `xenbr1` to `xenbr0`.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to assign 85.25.14.195 as alias IP on virbr0 ( may be virbr0:1 ) and do simple IP Nat or forwarding. You need to do # sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1  to be able to forward traffic coming on Public IP to internal Private IP.